# Как реализовать переход на карточку продукта через js, html

Tags: javascript, html

Есть таблица продуктов, и при нажатии на наименование продукта необходимо переходить на карточку этого продукта, где будет из базы данных подгружаться информация по ней. Вопрос, как реализовать этот процесс только с помощью чистого js, html?

Comment: Нужно где-то в строке (data-атрибуте) хранить идентификацию продукта (например его ИД)... При клике считывать ее и делать переход на нужную страницу с параметрами? Например так `top.location = url + '?id=' + id`